# Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x000007FEC61F3590 (ig4icd64.dll)

Tags: c++, opengl

При компиляции проблем нет, а при запуске прога ломается.
Где-то в функции glEnableVertexAttribArray и glDisableVertexAttribArray происходит исключение:
Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x000007FEC61F3590 (ig4icd64.dll) в Project1.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x0000000000000000.
Вот код:

```
//Главный файл
#include <iostream>
#include "VAO.h"
using namespace gl;

int main() {
    if(!glfwInit()) std::cout << "Failed to init glfw!\n";
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(850, 650, "Test", nullptr, nullptr);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glewExperimental = true;
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) std::cout << "Failed to init glew\n";
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    glVertexArrayObject vao;
    vao.createVBO({ 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f });




    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        vao.draw(3);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    system("pause");
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

```
//файл VAO.h
#pragma once
#include <glew.h>
//#include <glut.h>
#include <glfw3.h>
#include <vector>

namespace gl {
    class glVertexArrayObject {
    public:
        glVertexArrayObject();
        glVertexArrayObject(const glVertexArrayObject&) = delete;
        ~glVertexArrayObject();
        void bind();
        void createVBO(const std::vector<float>& data);
        void draw(GLsizei size);
    private:
        GLuint myVertexArrayObject;
        std::vector<GLuint> allBuffers;
    };
}
```

```
//файл VAO.cpp
#include "VAO.h"

gl::glVertexArrayObject::glVertexArrayObject() {
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &myVertexArrayObject);
}

void gl::glVertexArrayObject::bind() {
    glBindVertexArray(myVertexArrayObject);
}

void gl::glVertexArrayObject::createVBO(const std::vector<float>& data) {
        bind();
    GLuint VertexBufferObject;
    glGenBuffers(1, &VertexBufferObject);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexBufferObject);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, data.size() * sizeof(float), data.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(allBuffers.size(), 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, nullptr);
    allBuffers.push_back(VertexBufferObject);
}

void gl::glVertexArrayObject::draw(GLsizei size) {
    bind();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < allBuffers.size(); ++i) {
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(i);
    }
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, size);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < allBuffers.size(); ++i) {
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(i);
    }
}

gl::glVertexArrayObject::~glVertexArrayObject() {
    glDeleteBuffers(allBuffers.size(), allBuffers.data());
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &myVertexArrayObject);
}
```

Comment: самое обыкновынное разыменовывание нулевого указателя - берите дебаггер и пошагово выполняйте пока прога не упадет

Comment: я бы мог попробовать отладить, но копировать и создавать 3 файла мне не хочется, вот был бы 1 файл... в коде не вижу ничего приводящего к крашу

Comment: Спасибо за внимание! В коде ошибок нет, вызывается исключение при запуске программы. Я думал проблема с видеоадаптером, но нет, с ним всё нормально. Приложение запускается, открывает окно, а при попытке рисовать массив, выдаёт исключение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена:
Я собрал проект с конфигурацией *64, а нужно было с *32. Не знаю почему так)